# What happens if unique_ptr custom deleter has an error or fails and how do you check it?

Tags: c++, error-handling, unique-ptr

I have looked all over and haven't been able to find a good answer - maybe not using the right search terms - so - how do you check if a unique_ptr's custom deleter fails and how do you handle the error?  I am trying to wrap libzip by creating a ZipArchive class.  In libzip, you close a file using the function:

```
int zip_close(zip_t* archive);
```

It returns 0 on success and -1 for failure and sets an error conditon in "archive". I know this is easily done with raw pointers, but I was trying to use a unique_ptr:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<zip_t, int(*)(zip_t*)> UniqueArchive;
```

and later

```
mArchive = UniqueArchive(pointer_to_archive, zip_close);
```

(mArchive is a private member of the ZipArchive class)

Later on, when ZipArchive is destroyed and mArchive is cleaned up, how would you make it so you could check if zip_close was successful?  Right now I can think of wrapping zip_close in a function that has some error handling - maybe throws an exception, but how would you even check that?  If there was an error, it would then throw an exception from the destructor wouldn't it?

Anyway - hope my question makes sense - thanks for any guidance!

Comment: It seems to me that `zip_close()` should be an explicit operation, as it effectively commits any changes made to disk. I'd recommend that the automatic deletion action be `zip_discard()` instead. Compare this to a database transaction handle, where the usual default behavior for the handle being released is to roll back the open transaction instead of committing it. However, then you have to deal with the possibility that `zip_close()` was already called. It may be useful to wrap a `zip_t*` in a proper class with a destructor that can handle this complexity instead of a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Ahh - I did not see zip_discard.  I think that is the way to go, and I think your idea of wrapping zip_t in a class is a better idea - and if you really want to use a unique_pointer, have it point to that class.... Thanks for the insight!